# Run macro based on similar tab names

Tags: excel, vba

[image: SS]

I have attempted to use [the solution provided by CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60966061/2422013) however using `INDIRECT` slows down my workbook and eventually causes it to freeze. Is there any workaround that doesn't use `INDIRECT` (which is a volatile function)?

I'm currently using it for quite a number of cells (we're looking at thousands), is there any substitute for it?

I have the following tabs:

```
001, 002, 003, Assessment Form 001, Assessment Form 002, Assessment Form 003
```

I would like the tab for `Assessment Form 001` to perform a vlookup on the data available in `001`; so on and so forth (eg. `Assessment Form 002` vlookup from `002`, `Assessment Form 003` vlookup from `003`).

So if the tab name for `Assessment Form 001` contains `001`, it should then vlookup to the tab which is `001`, etc etc.

Comment: Have a look at the `INDIRECT` function. Also the `CELL` function to retrieve the tab name of a cell. No need for vba at all.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, never thought of indirect function! Let me check that out. Thanks!

Comment: I am still open to any suggestions with regards to this! Thanks everyone :)

Comment: As per your new question please be aware that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, we don't have threads here :-). I've bountied your question to draw attention so hopefully you'll receive an answer that doesn't slow down your workbook and freeze it. You might also want to unmark CLR's answer as accepted since it has issues.

Comment: Thanks a million AStopher! I couldn't thank you enough for all these help so far.

Comment: @AStopher - You achieved you goal...

Comment: **AStopher, Sanchi.s and CLR** you guys were great... I couldn't help to think that this community is THIS generous! Once again, thanks everyone...

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I did, but Stack Overflow requires a minimum of 24 hours before I can award the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering your question:

**... Is there any workaround that doesn't use INDIRECT (which is a volatile function)?**

Or **... is there any substitute for it?** (essentially rephrased)

You can use VBA.
The following function worked for me

```
Public Function shifted_lookup(lookup_value As Variant, table_array As Range, column_index As Integer, range_lookup As Integer) As Variant
    Dim curr_wsname As String, oth_wsname As String
    Dim curr_ws As Worksheet, oth_ws As Worksheet
    Set curr_ws = ActiveSheet
    curr_wsname = curr_ws.Name
    oth_wsname = Right(curr_wsname, 3)
    Set oth_ws = Worksheets(oth_wsname)
    Dim src_rng_base As String, src_rng As Range
    src_rng_base = table_array.Address
    Set src_rng = oth_ws.Range(src_rng_base)
    Dim aux As Variant
    shifted_lookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup_value, src_rng, column_index, range_lookup)
End Function
```

The example that I used to test (I have Excel in Spanish):

[image]
[image]

The formulas are:

B1: `=shifted_lookup(A1,$A$1:$B$6,2,1)`

B2: `=shifted_lookup(A2,$A$1:$B$6,2,0)`

B3: `=shifted_lookup(A3,$A$1:$B$6,2,1)`

B4: `=shifted_lookup(A4,$A$1:$B$6,2,0)`

B5: `=shifted_lookup(A5,$A$1:$B$6,2,1)`

Notes:

1. I wouldn't know about the performance or possible freezes, I didn't set up a "testbed" for this.
2. You may want to work out `range_lookup As Integer` as an optional parameter, similarly as in `VLOOKUP`.
3. You could shorten a little the function, removing some intermediate variables.
   They were defined for easier autocompletion, code writing, and debugging.
   I don't think it would help in any way, though.

Comment: Sancho.s, perfect!!! It works perfectly for me :) I really thank you for the help, really really appreciative your hardwork and help in this. I'm gonna go ahead and check this as the satisfactory answer. Just one question though, do you by any chance know how i could use your code and perform a vlookup which might have multiple results? So assuming there are multiple 'bre', i just want them to concat and join together. Attached below in the comment is the code i'm using to perform that function.

Comment: `Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = ""
    For Each rng In pWorkRng
        If rng = pValue Then
            xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
        End If
    Next
    MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function`

Comment: @JoshNg - I suggest you post another question, specifying the input and expected output.
Even in simple cases as this, lack of specification often leads to misguided work.

Comment: Definitely! Thank you so so much :))

Comment: you mind if i reach out to you on some other communication platform? I've got some queries with regards to it! Wouldn't want to flood irrelevant stuff over here. If not, its fine too! You've helped more than I could ask for :))

Comment: @JoshNg - I guess in any case, the best option by far is SO. Any one would be able to see your questions.
If you want to let somebody be aware about a post, you can always use @<user> in a comment in another post (preferably related).

Comment: @JoshNg - I guess you can only @<somebody> in a comment to an answer/question where <somebody> also commented. Otherwise, <somebody> (in this case, me) would not get any notification.

Comment: here's the link the question. I'm pretty sure I've violated the overflow rules for cross posting. But  imma give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366360/vlookup-with-multiple-results-across-similar-sheet-name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212318/discussion-between-josh-ng-and-sancho-s-reinstatemonicacellio).

Answer (score 2):

Entering the following formula on any worksheet will give you the last 3 characters of that sheet name.

```
=RIGHT(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,255),3)
```

So, combining this with the `INDIRECT` function, you can do this:

```
=VLOOKUP(lookupvalue,INDIRECT(RIGHT(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,255),3)&"!A:B"),2,0)
```

Where `lookupvalue` is what you're looking up, and `A:B` is the range on sheets 001,002 etc. that you're performing the lookup upon.

---

*Just to add to the above, for any future enquirers - the `CELL("filename")` function as provided above will only work once a file has been saved once.*

Comment: Thanks so much! It works when I put it into the cells! :)  I guess i'll play around with it from now on!

Comment: Hey CLR! I'm sorry to reopen this at this point of time. But by any chance, would you have another formula without the use if INDIRECT? I'm using it for vast amount of cells, and it seems to have made my workbook extremely slow and hangs eventually. Im so sorry to bother again..

Comment: You could put the value of `=RIGHT(MID(CELL("filename",$A$1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",$A$1))+1,255),3)` in a cell out of the way, perhaps hidden - so this is only 'calculated' once, and then have lots of quicker `=VLOOKUP(lookupvalue,INDIRECT([hidden_cell_location]&"!A:B"),2,0)`...? That might make it a lot quicker.

Comment: Also, reducing the range from `A:B` to a smaller range if known will make it quicker too. e.g. `A1:B150`.

Comment: Hello CLR! I've tried your method. Unfortunately, my computer still freezes and i have to force close excel.. I'm sorry for the trouble so far :(

Comment: Just a thought though, perhaps Vlookup (being volatile) could be a reason why my computer is running slow? Will index match work here in this case?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a much quicker alternative. You could in theory write some VBA that populates the table with lots of VLOOKUPs that have the codes built in but that is still going to be slow. I'm also not convinced Index/Match is going to be quicker than VLOOKUP.